# Redirect Url not working properly

Tags: php, facebook-apps

I am trying to access facebook contacts, the code works fine but when in try to logout , the redirect Url doesnot work, Instead it is Redirected to the User's Facebook home page.

```
<?php
require './src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'App ID',
    'secret' => 'App Secret',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    $facebook->destroySession();
    header("location: skifi.zapto.org/affiliates/index.php");
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/src/facebook.php';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/src/facebook.php';
} else {
    echo 'Facebook SDK Not Found';
    exit;
}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'App ID',
    'secret' => 'App Secret',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with Location with a capital L and http://

```
header("Location: http://skifi.zapto.org/affiliates/index.php");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php

Comment: Capital `L` is not really necessary but the `http://` is. Which, you made a slight typo. You wrote `hhtp://`

Comment: still not working, as i click the logout link I'm redirected to facebook home page.

Comment: Are you sure that your header location is called ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, seems to be working on my localhost.

```
$redirect_page = "http://skifi.zapto.org/affiliates/index.php";
header('Location: ' . $redirect_page);
exit();
```

Comment: it works fine on the local host but when i upload my code on the server, it doesn't work.

Comment: not sure why it is not working at your end, here is the link on my server where the code is working www.clickteck.com/clients/test.php

Comment: may be you need to check your `if ($user) {...}` and i see you have two `if`s for same things, and i also dont see how you are logging out, i understand the index.php but what is the code on top for?

Comment: the code on top is for logging out,basically destroying the session to log the user out.

Comment: are they on two different files? can you remove the `if ($user) {...}` in `index.php` and check if it works?